# 「preg_replace()」を「preg_replace_callback()」もしくは「preg_replace_callback_array()」へ書き直すには？

Tags: php, 正規表現

**やりたいこと**
・下記コードをPHP7で動作させたい
・e修飾子が原因であることは分かったのですが…

```
<?php
$html = "hoge"; 
$search = array ("'正規表現1'",
           "'正規表現2'",
           "'正規表現3'",
           "'&#(d+);'e");
$replace = array (" ",
                " ",
                " ",
                ' ');
var_dump(preg_replace($search, $replace, $html));
```

---

**Q1.そもそも下記はどういう意味でしょうか？**

> '&#(d+);'e

---

**Q2.何へ修正するのでしょうか？**
・preg_replace_callback()？
・それとも配列だから、preg_replace_callback_array()？

---

**Q3.どうやって修正するのでしょうか？**

---

**追記**
・実際のコード(の一部)です
・$searchも$replaceも配列要素数が14あったので、関係ないと思った箇所は削除して質問したのですが…
・search配列の一番最後の要素が「"'&#(d+);'e"」でした
・$htmlはダミーで文字列を入れていますが、実際にはHTMLタグ格納を想定していると思います

```
$replace = array (" ", 
                " ", 
                " ", 
                " ", 
                " \" ", 
                " & ", 
                " ", 
                " ", 
                " ", 
                ' ', 
                ' ', 
                ' ', 
                ' ', 
                ' ');
return strip_tags ( クラス名::メソッド名(preg_replace($search, $replace, $html)) );
```

Comment: `$replace`の中身を端折ってしまっていませんか? 現在掲載されているコードだと`e`オプションをつける意味が全くないので、`$search`の最後の`e`を削ればPHP7でも動くはずです、としか言えません。

Comment: $replace部分を追記しました

Comment: 追記後の`$replace`にもPHPの式は含まれていませんので、やはり「`$search`の最後の`e`を削ればPHP7でも動くはず‌​です」ですね。`e`オプションは、`$replace`の文字列の後方参照を解決した後にPHPの式として評価(いわゆる`eval`)してから元の文字列の置き換えに使う、というものですので、`$replace`の中にPHPの式として解釈できる文字列が含まれない場合には意味を持ちません。(別のところでは式を入れていた、と言うコードを流用したのかも知れません。)`"'&#(d+);'e"`の部分も本当は`"'&#(\\d+);'e"`じゃないかと思うのですが…。流用を続けるうちにそこらへんも欠落してしまったのかも知れませんが。(`'&#(d+);'`だと、`&#d;` `&#dd;` `&#ddd;`... と言う文字列にしかマッチしません。HTMLに適用するパターンとしては意味がないですね。)

Comment: なるほど、eオプションを使用する場合、replaceの中‌​に本来であれば「PHPの式として解釈できる文字列が含ま‌​れているはず」なのですね。参考になりました